# Procedure Results with Variable Column Alias - PLSQL/Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I've got this procedure working in TOAD/PLSQL but, would like the alias for the first column to be set to the field_name argument passed to the procedure.  I think I need to build the query as a string like,

```
query := 'Select 1 as ' || field_name || ' From Dual';
```

But am not getting it right.  Is what I have in mind possible?

Thanks and the working code I'm trying to modify is below.

```
Create or Replace Procedure Delete_Me(field_name NVarChar2)
as
result_set sys_refcursor;

BEGIN

open result_set for 

    Select
         Elapsed_Time((Select Start_Time From Temp_Time1)) as field_name
        ,To_Char(SysDate, 'HH12:MI:SS AM') as Time_Completed
        ,Elapsed_Time((Select Start_Time From Temp_Time0)) as Process_So_Far
    From
         Dual;

    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(result_set);     

End;
```

After comment:

I pass the procedure a string and its valued is placed in, "field_name."  I would like the alias of the first column to adopt the value of field_name.  So if I call the procedure thusly:

```
BEGIN
DeleteMe('Random_Column_Name');
END;
```

The first column name would be called, "Random_Column Name."  If I called the procedure this way:

```
BEGIN
DeleteMe('Different_Column_Name');
END;
```

The first column would be names, "Different_Column_Name."

After Dmitry's second comment:
It doesn't mean anything.  It's an example of what I've tried and failed to get to work.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add an example of what you have now and what you want to get? Currently, it is hard to understand.

Comment: The SQL for your cursor should be constructed by concatenating the alias variable with other parts.The variable for the alias should be outside quotes.

Comment: The string `query := 'Select 1 as ' || field_name || ' From Dual';` - what does it mean? Where did you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you need to make a dynamic query, the way to do that is sometihing like this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE ty_refcur IS REF CURSOR;

    c_mycur  ty_refcur;
    whatever varchar2(200) := 'whatever';
    my_query varchar2(500);

BEGIN
    my_query := 'Select ''hello''as '||whatever||' from dual';
    OPEN c_mycur FOR my_query;
      --whatever you want to do
    CLOSE   c_mycur;
END;
```

Comment: Excellent!  This is the right idea but, I need it to be a procedure and return the results.  And I'm sorry but, I'm not following the "Whatever I want to do."  I want it to return the results of the my_query string you built.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, with --whatever you want to do i mean, you can copy and paste your own beheavor, the same you have in your question code.  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(result_set); about the procedure, the code that i paste is the same like the body of a procedure, only get out the DECLARE and it's a procedure body.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally came up with.  Stanimir helped me understand how variables are used.  Thanks for that!

```
Create or Replace Procedure Report_Elapsed_Time(field_name0 NVarChar2,
                                                field_name1 NVarChar2)
    as
    result_set sys_refcursor;
        query VarChar2(30000);
    BEGIN

        query := 'Select
                         Elapsed_Time((Select Start_Time From Temp_Time1)) as ' || Replace(field_name0, ' ', '_') || '
                        ,To_Char(SysDate, ''HH12:MI:SS AM'') as Time_Completed
                        ,Elapsed_Time((Select Start_Time From Temp_Time0)) as ' || Replace(field_name1, ' ', '_') || '
                  From
                         Dual';

        open result_set for query;

        DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(result_set);     

    End;
```